# My plot in ipython does not show with pyplot.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

Help required displaying `matplotlib` plots in `ipython`. I did not forget to call `pyplot.show()`.

#### $ ipython --pylab

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(20), range(20))
```

It returns `matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xade2b2c` as the output.

```
plt.show()
```

Nothing happens. No error message. No new window. I installed `matplotlib` with `pip`, and no error messages occurred.

Details:

I use,

- Ubuntu
- IPython v0.11
- Python v2.6.6
- matplotlib v1.0.1

Comment: `pylab` is dead. [Which is the recommended way to plot: matplotlib or pylab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16849483/7758804). Disregard answers with `pylab`.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

If I set my backend to `template` in `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`,
then I can reproduce your symptoms:

~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc:

```
# backend      : GtkAgg
backend      : template
```

Note that the file `matplotlibrc` may not be in directory `~/.matplotlib/`. In this case, the following code shows where it is:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

---

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as p

In [2]: p.plot(range(20),range(20))
Out[2]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xa64932c>]

In [3]: p.show()
```

---

If you edit `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` and change the backend to something like `GtkAgg`, you should see a plot. You can list all the backends available on your machine with

```
import matplotlib.rcsetup as rcsetup
print(rcsetup.all_backends)
```

It should return a list like:

```
['GTK', 'GTKAgg', 'GTKCairo', 'FltkAgg', 'MacOSX', 'QtAgg', 'Qt4Agg',
'TkAgg', 'WX', 'WXAgg', 'CocoaAgg', 'agg', 'cairo', 'emf', 'gdk', 'pdf',
'ps', 'svg', 'template']
```

Reference:

- [Customizing matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)

Answer (score 75):

I ran into the exact same problem on Ubuntu 12.04, because I installed matplotlib (within a virtualenv) using

```
pip install matplotlib
```

To make long story short, my advice is: don't try to install matplotlib using pip or by hand; let a real package manager (e.g. apt-get / synaptic) install it and all its dependencies for you.

Unfortunately, matplotlib's backends (alternative methods for actually rendering your plots) have all sorts of dependencies that pip will not deal with.  Even worse, it fails silently; that is, `pip install matplotlib` appears to install matplotlib successfully.  But when you try to use it (e.g. `pyplot.show()`), no plot window will appear.  I tried all the different backends that people on the web suggest (Qt4Agg, GTK, etc.), and they all failed (i.e. when I tried to import matplotlib.pyplot, I get `ImportError` because it's trying to import some dependency that's missing).  I then researched how to install those dependencies, but it just made me want to give up using pip (within virtualenv) as a viable installation solution for any package that has non-Python package dependencies.

The whole experience sent me crawling back to apt-get / synaptic (i.e. the Ubuntu package manager) to install software like matplotlib.  That worked perfectly.  Of course, that means you can only install into your system directories, no virtualenv goodness, and you are stuck with the versions that Ubuntu distributes, which may be way behind the current version...

Answer (score 46):

Add `%matplotlib inline` once to the notebook, prior to plotting.

Comment: This question is about ipython, not jupyter notebooks

Answer (score 13):

Just type:

`plt.ion()`

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zmV8lZsHF4 at 23:30 !

`plt` is used because of my import: `import matplotlib.pyplot` as plt

I'm using python2.7 on a mac with iTerm2.

Answer (score 11):

For future reference,

I have encountered the same problem -- pylab was not showing under ipython.  The problem was fixed by changing ipython's config file {ipython_config.py}.  In the config file

`c.InteractiveShellApp.pylab = 'auto'`

I changed 'auto' to 'qt' and now I see graphs

Answer (score 10):

What solved my problem was just using the below two lines in ipython notebook at the top

```
%matplotib inline
%pylab inline
```

And it worked. I'm using Ubuntu16.04 and ipython-5.1

Comment: `pylab` is dead. [Which is the recommended way to plot: matplotlib or pylab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16849483/7758804)

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following two lines before importing pylab seems to work for me

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("gtk")

import sys
import pylab
import numpy as np
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to install matplotlib from source to get this to work. The key instructions (from http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/08/24/resolved-matplotlib-figures-not-showing-up-or-displaying/) are:

```
$ workon plotting
$ pip uninstall matplotlib
$ git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
$ cd matplotlib
$ python setup.py install
```

By changing the backend, as @unutbu says, I just ran into loads more problems with all the different backends not working either.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Rikki, I solved this problem by upgrading `matplotlib` with `pip install matplotlib --upgrade`. If you can't upgrade uninstalling and reinstalling may work.

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 1):

After running your code include:

```
import pylab as p
p.show()
```

Comment: `pylab` is dead. [Which is the recommended way to plot: matplotlib or pylab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16849483/7758804)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have this startup script enabled :
( Preferences > Console > Advanced Options )

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/scientific_startup.py
```

If the standard PYTHONSTARTUP is enabled you won't have an interactive plot

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem happens if I simply create an *empty* `matplotlibrc` file under `~/.matplotlib` on macOS. Adding "backend: macosx" in it fixes the problem.

I think it is a bug: if `backend` is not specified in my `matplotlibrc` it should take the default value.

Answer (score 0):

if you are a nube from ruby, don't forget the parenthesis - `show()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `yolov5` the fixes described here might not work as in my case. YOLOv5 developers have turned off the preview of the images using `plt.show()`, so most likely this will happen to you. To resolve make sure that your environment is correctly configured using requirements.txt file that comes with yolov5 and then use the workaround:

```
import torch
import matplotlib

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s') # Load model first
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') # Change backend after loading model
```

as described here: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/2779
you can also try another backend from the ones mentioned above like `'Qt4Agg'` or smth else.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great long-term solution, but if none of this is working for you, you can get around it by using this instead of `p.show()`:

```
p.savefig("output_plot.png")
```

This will create the plot image in the same directory. You can open it separately in a normal image viewer.

Answer (score -1):

I found that I needed `window = Tk()` and then `window.mainloop()`

Answer (score -2):

For Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
virtualenv .env --no-site-packages
source .env/bin/activate
easy_install -U distribute
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4 .
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.so .
pip install matplotlib
```