# pyplot.show() doesn't work when importing a certain function

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Importing the function single_snp from Microsoft's program "FaSTLMM" prevents python2.7 from displaying matplotlib plots. The plot is correctly displayed when omitting the import. How does importing this function interfere with the plotting of pyplot? (I need single_snp to perform a calculation which is used in the plot I really want to display.)

```
from fastlmm.association import single_snp

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

The source code for single_snp can be found here: https://github.com/MicrosoftGenomics/FaST-LMM/blob/master/fastlmm/association/single_snp.py

I tried different backends (see [Why doesn't pyplot.show() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557704/why-doesnt-pyplot-show-work)), but to no avail.

Comment: Just to be clear: the above minimal example doesn't show the plot for you? And if you remove the import, it shows? And if so: are you sure it's just the plot not showing? If you leave a `print` before the `plt.show()` line, does it print?

Comment: Exactly: the above code does not show the plot, removing the import makes the plot show up and the plot is the only thing not working, i.e. putting 'print' functions before and after 'plt.show' works as expected, despite of the import.

Comment: That sounds *very* odd. Although [it should not matter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26804809/5067311), you should try importing pyplot first. Otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: If you can't figure it out, it's probably worth opening an issue in github.

Comment: Importing pyplot first actually solved it. Very odd indeed. Thank you a lot.

Comment: https://youtu.be/5XvAVgcbmdY might be helpful figuring out the issue

Comment: How are you running the code?