# Error matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x025B8350

Tags: matplotlib, python-2.7

```
>>> import pylab as pl
>>> x = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi, 100)
>>> pl.plot(x, np.sin(x))
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x025B8350>]
```

after install numpy, scipy, sympy, matplotlib, ipython

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                              Python 2.7.3: C:\Python27\python.exe
                                                   Fri Sep 28 09:59:01 2012
A problem occured executing Python code.  Here is the sequence of function
calls leading up to the error, with the most recent (innermost) call last.

C:\Python27\scripts\ipython.py in <module>()
     13 
     14 [or simply IPython.Shell.IPShell().mainloop(1) ]
     15 
     16 and IPython will be your working environment when you start python. The final
     17 sys.exit() call will make python exit transparently when IPython finishes, so
     18 you don't have an extra prompt to get out of.
     19 
     20 This is probably useful to developers who manage multiple Python versions and
     21 don't want to have correspondingly multiple IPython versions. Note that in
     22 this mode, there is no way to pass IPython any command-line options, as those
     23 are trapped first by Python itself.
     24 """
     25 
     26 import IPython.Shell
     27 
---> 28 IPython.Shell.start().mainloop()
        global IPython.Shell.start.mainloop = undefined
     29 
     30 
     31 
     32 
     33 
     34 
     35 
     36 
     37 
     38 
     39 
     40 
     41 
     42 
     43 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\Shell.pyc in start(user_ns=None)
   1244 
   1245         # New versions of pygtk don't need the brittle threaded support.
   1246         th_mode = check_gtk(th_mode)
   1247         return th_shell[th_mode]
   1248 
   1249 
   1250 # This is the one which should be called by external code.
   1251 def start(user_ns = None):
   1252     """Return a running shell instance, dealing with threading options.
   1253 
   1254     This is a factory function which will instantiate the proper IPython shell
   1255     based on the user's threading choice.  Such a selector is needed because
   1256     different GUI toolkits require different thread handling details."""
   1257 
   1258     shell = _select_shell(sys.argv)
-> 1259     return shell(user_ns = user_ns)
   1260 
   1261 # Some aliases for backwards compatibility
   1262 IPythonShell = IPShell
   1263 IPythonShellEmbed = IPShellEmbed
   1264 #************************ End of file <Shell.py> ***************************
   1265 
   1266 
   1267 
   1268 
   1269 
   1270 
   1271 
   1272 
   1273 
   1274 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\Shell.pyc in __init__(self=<IPython.Shell.IPShell instance>, argv=None, user_ns=None, user_global_ns=None, debug=1, shell_class=<class 'IPython.iplib.InteractiveShell'>)
     58 # Default timeout for waiting for multithreaded shells (in seconds)
     59 GUI_TIMEOUT = 10
     60 
     61 #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     62 # This class is trivial now, but I want to have it in to publish a clean
     63 # interface. Later when the internals are reorganized, code that uses this
     64 # shouldn't have to change.
     65 
     66 class IPShell:
     67     """Create an IPython instance."""
     68     
     69     def __init__(self,argv=None,user_ns=None,user_global_ns=None,
     70                  debug=1,shell_class=InteractiveShell):
     71         self.IP = make_IPython(argv,user_ns=user_ns,
     72                                user_global_ns=user_global_ns,
---> 73                                debug=debug,shell_class=shell_class)
        global For = undefined
        global more = undefined
        global details = undefined
        global see = undefined
        global the = undefined
        global __call__ = undefined
        global method = undefined
        global below. = undefined
     74 
     75     def mainloop(self,sys_exit=0,banner=None):
     76         self.IP.mainloop(banner)
     77         if sys_exit:
     78             sys.exit()
     79 
     80 #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     81 def kill_embedded(self,parameter_s=''):
     82     """%kill_embedded : deactivate for good the current embedded IPython.
     83 
     84     This function (after asking for confirmation) sets an internal flag so that
     85     an embedded IPython will never activate again.  This is useful to
     86     permanently disable a shell that is being called inside a loop: once you've
     87     figured out what you needed from it, you may then kill it and the program
     88     will then continue to run without the interactive shell interfering again.

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\ipmaker.pyc in make_IPython(argv=[r'C:\Python27\scripts\ipython.py'], user_ns=None, user_global_ns=None, debug=1, rc_override=None, shell_class=<class 'IPython.iplib.InteractiveShell'>, embedded=False, **kw={})
    506     # tweaks. Basically options which affect other options. I guess this
    507     # should just be written so that options are fully orthogonal and we
    508     # wouldn't worry about this stuff!
    509 
    510     if IP_rc.classic:
    511         IP_rc.quick = 1
    512         IP_rc.cache_size = 0
    513         IP_rc.pprint = 0
    514         IP_rc.prompt_in1 = '>>> '
    515         IP_rc.prompt_in2 = '... '
    516         IP_rc.prompt_out = ''
    517         IP_rc.separate_in = IP_rc.separate_out = IP_rc.separate_out2 = '0'
    518         IP_rc.colors = 'NoColor'
    519         IP_rc.xmode = 'Plain'
    520 
--> 521     IP.pre_config_initialization()
    522     # configure readline
    523 
    524     # update exception handlers with rc file status
    525     otrap.trap_out()  # I don't want these messages ever.
    526     IP.magic_xmode(IP_rc.xmode)
    527     otrap.release_out()
    528 
    529     # activate logging if requested and not reloading a log
    530     if IP_rc.logplay:
    531         IP.magic_logstart(IP_rc.logplay + ' append')
    532     elif  IP_rc.logfile:
    533         IP.magic_logstart(IP_rc.logfile)
    534     elif IP_rc.log:
    535         IP.magic_logstart()
    536 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\iplib.pyc in pre_config_initialization(self=<IPython.iplib.InteractiveShell object>)
    820                           self.user_ns,  # globals
    821                           # Skip our own frame in searching for locals:
    822                           sys._getframe(depth+1).f_locals # locals
    823                           ))
    824 
    825     def pre_config_initialization(self):
    826         """Pre-configuration init method
    827 
    828         This is called before the configuration files are processed to
    829         prepare the services the config files might need.
    830         
    831         self.rc already has reasonable default values at this point.
    832         """
    833         rc = self.rc
    834         try:
--> 835             self.db = pickleshare.PickleShareDB(rc.ipythondir + "/db")
        global Optional = undefined
        global inputs = undefined
    836         except exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError:
    837             print "Your ipythondir can't be decoded to unicode!"
    838             print "Please set HOME environment variable to something that"
    839             print r"only has ASCII characters, e.g. c:\home"
    840             print "Now it is",rc.ipythondir
    841             sys.exit()
    842         self.shadowhist = IPython.history.ShadowHist(self.db)
    843 
    844     def post_config_initialization(self):
    845         """Post configuration init method
    846 
    847         This is called after the configuration files have been processed to
    848         'finalize' the initialization."""
    849 
    850         rc = self.rc

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\Extensions\pickleshare.pyc in __init__(self=PickleShareDB('C:\Documents and Settings\martinhylee\_ipython\db'), root=u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\martinhylee\\_ipython/db')
     38 import cPickle as pickle
     39 import UserDict
     40 import warnings
     41 import glob
     42 
     43 def gethashfile(key):
     44     return ("%02x" % abs(hash(key) % 256))[-2:]
     45 
     46 _sentinel = object()
     47 
     48 class PickleShareDB(UserDict.DictMixin):
     49     """ The main 'connection' object for PickleShare database """
     50     def __init__(self,root):
     51         """ Return a db object that will manage the specied directory"""
     52         self.root = Path(root).expanduser().abspath()
---> 53         if not self.root.isdir():
     54             self.root.makedirs()
     55         # cache has { 'key' : (obj, orig_mod_time) }
     56         self.cache = {}
     57         
     58 
     59     def __getitem__(self,key):
     60         """ db['key'] reading """
     61         fil = self.root / key
     62         try:
     63             mtime = (fil.stat()[stat.ST_MTIME])
     64         except OSError:
     65             raise KeyError(key)
     66 
     67         if fil in self.cache and mtime == self.cache[fil][1]:
     68             return self.cache[fil][0]

TypeError: _isdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

**********************************************************************

Oops, IPython crashed. We do our best to make it stable, but...

A crash report was automatically generated with the following information:
  - A verbatim copy of the crash traceback.
  - A copy of your input history during this session.
  - Data on your current IPython configuration.

It was left in the file named:
    'C:\Documents and Settings\martinhylee\_ipython\IPython_crash_report.txt'
If you can email this file to the developers, the information in it will help
them in understanding and correcting the problem.

You can mail it to: Fernando Perez at fperez.net@gmail.com
with the subject 'IPython Crash Report'.

If you want to do it now, the following command will work (under Unix):
mail -s 'IPython Crash Report' fperez.net@gmail.com < C:\Documents and Settings\martinhylee\_ipython\IPython_crash_report.txt

To ensure accurate tracking of this issue, please file a report about it at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ipython/+filebug

Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\CrashHandler.py", line 157, in __call__
    report.write(self.make_report(traceback))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\CrashHandler.py", line 215, in make_report
    rpt_add('BZR revision   : %s \n\n' % Release.revision)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'revision'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\scripts\ipython.py", line 28, in <module>
    IPython.Shell.start().mainloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\Shell.py", line 1259, in start
    return shell(user_ns = user_ns)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\Shell.py", line 73, in __init__
    debug=debug,shell_class=shell_class)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\ipmaker.py", line 521, in make_IPython
    IP.pre_config_initialization()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\iplib.py", line 835, in pre_config_initialization
    self.db = pickleshare.PickleShareDB(rc.ipythondir + "/db")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\Extensions\pickleshare.py", line 53, in __init__
    if not self.root.isdir():
TypeError: _isdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from pylab import *
x = np.linspace(0.4 * np.pi, 100)
plot(x, np.sin(x))
show()
```