# matplotlib show nothing although i called show

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I am a newbie of matplotlib.

Recently I am using #WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.1# on #Win-7 64bit# and  When I typed codes on the IPython Qt Control as below:

```
In [1]: plot(range(3))    
Out[1]: [<.matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x64ae390>] 
% There is a plot. 
In [2]: show() 
%nothing happened.
```

There should be a plot after show. But nothing happed, no error message. And the savefig() will only save a blank fig.
I tried the solution of [matplotlib does not show my drawings although I call pyplot.show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show) by setting backends = 'GtkAgg' or 'QtAgg', but it did not work.

Thanks for your advice. :)

> **Updata1**:
>   The **'WinPython Interpreter.exe'** is used instead of **'IPython QT Console.exe'**. 
>   Then I typed the same code and the `show()` worked.
>   The backend is set to `GtkAgg`.
>
> I think the reason is as below:
>
> Since WinPythonInterpreter is a command window, it need a new window to display the plot.
>   The IPython supports interactive data visualization, it does not need another window.
>
> **Updata2**: I just fount that **the `gcf()` returned different references in the QT Console**, and **it returned the same reference in WinPython Interpreter**. Maybe this is the problem point.

Comment: `setting backends = 'GtkAgg' or 'QtAgg', but it did not work.` Did you get errors or just a blank figure? What is your default backend?

Comment: Did you start in pylab mode? Could you try that if not using the `--pylab` command line switch (in which case you shouldn't need the show statement anyway as it's 'interactive')

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano , I set the backends in the matplotlibrc file and nothing has changed. The default backends shall be the original: GTKAgg

Comment: does it work if you do `plot(list(range(3)))`?

Comment: Hi, @mutzmatron , I am using the WinPython on Windows and not sure whether it is in pylab mode. So i tried 'IPython Console Qt --pylab' in the cmd, nothing changed.

Comment: hi, @FrancescoMontesano , I did not try plot(list(range(3))). But When I do plot(range(3)), there will be Output and a plot.

Comment: I see that you're using python 3.3. I don't use it and I don't have matplotlib for python 3, but I know that `range` returns an iterator and not a list. I don't know if this can cause the problem that you have

Comment: Thanks, @FrancescoMontesano. I will try 'list(range(3))' when i get the computer. But I do not know how to make show() works.:D

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano, `list(range(3))` works, it will output a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

The WinPython IPython QT console appears to default to pylab with the inline backend as mutzmatron suggested in the comments.

It can be a little confusing to know what mode Matplotlib is working in see [Matplotlib pylab and pyplot: how they are related?](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pylab-and-pyplot-how-are-they-related)

I tend to use the Python distribution [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) it's QTConsole doesn't preload pylab by default so you can import pyplot and use show(), With WinPython you can launch the IPython QT console like this by going to the WinPython*\python*\Scripts directory with the windows command prompt and launching `ipython3.exe qtconsole`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(3))
plt.show()
```

Although that halts the execution in the IPython QT console when plot is open. You can detect which backend is being used by `plt.get_backend()`, the Anaconda IPython QT console uses `QT4Agg` on my Windows 7 install.

Comment: @semuas, Yes, the WinPython IPython QT console do preload pylab and matplotlib. But I dont think that's the reason. Maybe the gcf() returns different references cause this problem. I will update the details in my question.