# matplotlib plots do not show on Anaconda for Linux

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, ubuntu-12.04

I've read these and tried the solutions but still not getting anything to show:

[matplotlib show nothing although i called show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461302/matplotlib-show-nothing-although-i-called-show?lq=1)

[Why doesn't pyplot.show() work? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557704/why-doesnt-pyplot-show-work?lq=1)

[matplotlib does not show my drawings although I call pyplot.show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show)

I'm using Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.0 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 12.04.
How can I go about diagnosing the problem and trying to solve it?

EDIT:

-First I edited matplotlibrc and change the backend to GtkAgg (was set to QtAgg).

-Then I tried to change the backend via code: matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = "GtkAgg"

EDIT2 - adding detail from the Spyder console (no plot is shown at the end):

```
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 17 2014, 10:13:17) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Imported NumPy 1.8.0, SciPy 0.13.3, Matplotlib 1.3.1
Type "scientific" for more details.
>>> scientific

This is a standard Python interpreter with preloaded tools for scientific 
computing and visualization. It tries to import the following modules:

>>> import numpy as np  # NumPy (multidimensional arrays, linear algebra, ...)
>>> import scipy as sp  # SciPy (signal and image processing library)
>>> import matplotlib as mpl         # Matplotlib (2D/3D plotting library)
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # Matplotlib's pyplot: MATLAB-like syntax
>>> from pylab import *              # Matplotlib's pylab interface
>>> ion()                            # Turned on Matplotlib's interactive mode

Within Spyder, this interpreter also provides:
    * special commands (e.g. %ls, %pwd, %clear)
    * system commands, i.e. all commands starting with '!' are subprocessed
      (e.g. !dir on Windows or !ls on Linux, and so on)

>>> plot(range(3))
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x3f3cd50>]
>>> show()
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What backend, etc.?

Comment: What platform? are you trying the IPython notebook? are you getting any error message?

Comment: I'm using Anaconda 1.9.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. Same Anaconda I use on a W7 machine, where plots works just fine. Not trying to use IPython. Need the plots from Spyder.

Comment: do you have pygtk installed?

Comment: not familiar with it. I wouldn't have it unless it came with Anaconda.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up solving by doing this in Spyder:
Preferences -> Console -> External modules -> check Install Spyder's input hook for Qt

Comment: I was facing the same problem. Once I run and plotted anything trough Spyder in the conda environment I was able to plot in pycharm where the problem was. Magical thing or no we will never know... Congrats!

Answer (score 2):

In order for your `matplotlib` backend choice to work, you need to have the Python bindings for that backend installed. You may be running a GTK-based windows manager like GNOME, for example, but still not have the Python bindings around. According to [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pygtk), the proper Ubuntu package is `python-gtk`. So, open up your favorite Terminal emulator and enter

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtk
```

(you'll need admin privileges to do it). Restart your python/matplotlib session, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I get this error when I run that code in terminal: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-gtk

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mavericks, solved the problem by changing backend to Qt4Agg in matplotlibrc. (as instructed in another answer here: [Why doesn't pyplot.show() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557704/why-doesnt-pyplot-show-work?lq=1))