# I am having trouble plotting in iPython I do not know what backend to set

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm not getting a plot when I use iPython. My matplotlibrc is set to, backend : agg.
I found an answer: [matplotlib does not show my drawings although I call pyplot.show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show)

However, it doesn't tell me what I should do in my situation.

I have a remote iPython server. 
How do I get a plot to show in iPython?

Comment: why not try GtkAgg instead of agg?

Comment: there is no UI installed to the server of course. I ssh into it.  As well as, GTK is a very big package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to solve my own problem I found if I used `%matplotlib inline`, or `%pylab inline` I could plot the graph.