# Making plot in ipython with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I've been trying to make a scatter plot with the following code

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

If I type these commands line by line into ipython console, there is no graph displayed after the plt.show() command. However, if I copy and paste the whole code block into the console, the graph is displayed.

Has anyone had this issue before? What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @kvorobiev Nothing, not even a blank frame. x and y are two arrays of float type numbers defined somewhere else.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show).