# Message "Matplotlib is currently using agg" and Matplotlib doesn't display image

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Other people have this problem, I used their solutions but not solved.

I use `virtual env with python3.5`.
`Matplotlib` is installed under `virtual env`.
I have python3.tkinter installed at system.

When I check

```
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

I have

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.get_backend()
'TkAgg'
```

But when I run the code below

```
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
  #plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
  plt.imshow(image_np)
  plt.show()
```

I have problem as

```
 UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  % get_backend())
```

I put at header as

```
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams["backend"] = "TkAgg"
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
```

some people said it was solved, but I still have the same problem and `plt` doesn't display image.

Comment: Isn't the warning you get pretty clear? You need to use a GUI-type backend to get an image with `show()`. What system are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. This is warning. But the problem is image not displayed.

Comment: Have a look if there is any help in  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7534680/2454357), especially the part that shows how to find out which backends are available. Among many others, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20249447/2454357) shows how to change the current backend.

Comment: How do you execute your program? Which python command? What is the result of `which python3`? What if you replace `matplotlib.rcParams["backend"] = "TkAgg"` by `matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` ?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl `which python3` gives me `/home/cnv/venvpy3_cpu/bin/python3`.`matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` still has same warning and no image display.

Comment: Did you follow the first link by Thomas Kühn? What does `print(rcsetup.all_backends)` return?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Yes I followed. And found out that, `pip installation` inside `venv` doesn't make complete installation. So I need to remove `pip installation` and install again with `apt-get`. Then it is solved. I can display image now.

Comment: @ThomasKühn thank you

Answer (score 3):

As [you noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586504/message-matplotlib-is-currently-using-agg-and-matplotlib-doesnt-display-image#comment96000171_54586504), Matplotlib backends [sometimes require extra steps to run in virtual environments](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/faq/virtualenv_faq.html).

That being said, the documentation linked above also indicates that TkAgg should be available:

> [...] the Tk framework (TkAgg backend) does not require any external dependencies and is normally always available.

I use Ubuntu, and I assumed TkAgg would be relying on PyGObject. That option has a note itself that links to build instructions.

Following the [PyGObject build instructions](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devguide/dev_environ.html), I went to install its system [dependencies](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devguide/dev_environ.html#ubuntu-logo-ubuntu-debian-logo-debian):

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y python3-venv python3-wheel python3-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libgirepository1.0-dev build-essential \
  libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libsqlite3-dev wget \
  curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libcairo2-dev
```

Then added the following [Python dependencies](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devguide/dev_environ.html#projects-with-pygobject-dependencies) to my project's virtual environment:

- pycairo
- pygobject

```sh
# inside my project's virtual environment
pip install pycairo
pip install pygobject
```

Once that done, running my project as usual displayed the expected graph.

### Notes

- I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 and Python 3.6.8 in the virtual environment of my project.
- I skipped through most of the build instructions for PyGObject and only did what I described above.

Answer (score 3):

in my case, i solved it by replace pyplot function with PIL Image function:

(my guess is function went wrong for some image format)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTK3Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image


# plt.imshow(image_np)
# plt.show()
img = Image.fromarray(image_np, 'RGB')
img.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your code when you run it:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, make sure to check this checkbox during setup
[image]