# Graphs on Python as plt.plot wont show

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, graph

Hello i've been stuck on this for a while now. My graph wont show i'm unsure if its because of my while loop:

```
while True:
   temperature = input("Temperature in Kelvin. Type stop to finish")

   if temperature == "stop":
    break

   else:
     tempy = float(temperature)

   print (tempy)
```

and my plot:

```
  intensities=rad(lambda_range_metres,root_mean_square_dev)
# Plot the intensity values against the wavelength in millimetres
  plt.plot(lambda_range,intensities)
  plt.title('i')
  plt.xlabel('i /i ')
  plt.ylabel('i / i')
  plt.show()
```

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your loop surely has nothing to do with a problem. Checkout [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show), there are multiple possible ways to solve your problem. You can also try saving your figure with `plt.savefig('myfig.png')`. If successful, then it's most probably the backend problem as suggested in the selected answer to the referenced question.