# Figure not displayed while using matplotlib even when backend environment is correct

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have very similar problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show). However, my default backend environment is correct for both python 2.7 as well as 3.6.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

...gives me **TkAgg** and **GTK3Agg** respectively.

I haven't used python on this machine for months so I do not know exactly when this behaviour changed. I have used matplotlib before on this machine and it worked just fine.

Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: That issue is very old.  Can you give us more details.  How are you trying to run matplotlib?  What errors do you get?   What is in your .matplotlibrc? What version of matplotlib are you using?  etc

Comment: I get no errors. Nothing happens when I run my plotting script (same that worked earlier) and I return to prompt without the figure being displayed. Matplotlib version is 2.2.4. I'm not sure what exactly you want to know from .matplotlibrc, as I've mentioned the backend environments seems as suggested in the linked question. @JodyKlymak